# For loops are faster than pure numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

**[Disclosure: during writing this question, I found out what's going on, so I'll propose my own solution to the problem. If you have anything to add, I would be glad to read some other suggestions.]**

I'm working on a machine learning method, which involves running mathematical and image processing functions a huge number of times on small image crops. Currently what I wanted to achieve is to make the pipeline faster by optimizing these functions. Originally each training sample was processed separately in a for loop, so I thought that an easy improvement would be to combine the 2D numpy arrays (images) into a single 3D array, and process these together, without the for loop. I made some performance measurements, and I was shocked to see that processing in for loops were actually faster than pure numpy computations.

This is what I was doing (please find the complete script in the end). I ran the measurements with timeit. The setup code was the following (`init_script`):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
a = np.random.rand(30, 100, 100).astype(np.float32)
b = np.random.rand(30, 100, 100).astype(np.float32)
out = np.empty_like(a)
```

I compare calculating the pixelwise mean

- in a loop (`"np loop"`):

  ```py
  for i, (a_slice, b_slice) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
      out[i] = (a_slice+b_slice)/2
  ```
- operating on the whole array (`"pure np"`):

  ```py
  out[:] = (a+b)/2
  ```
- without copying (`"pure np (no copy)"`):

  ```py
  out = (a+b)/2
  ```

I do the same for sqrt; for the sake of completeness:

- loop:

  ```py
  for i, a_slice in enumerate(a):
      out[i] = np.sqrt(a_slice)
  ```
- numpy:

  ```py
  out[:] = np.sqrt(a)
  ```
- no copy:

  ```py
  out = np.sqrt(a)
  ```

The output I get for the measurements (running 10000 times):

```
=========mean==========
    np loop:  2939.34 ms
    pure np:  8441.93 ms
    pure np (no copy):  7417.07 ms
=========sqrt==========
    np loop:  1353.00 ms
    pure np:  4304.14 ms
    pure np (no copy):  3546.86 ms
```

With more samples (`arr_size = (100, 100, 100)`):

```
=========mean==========
    np loop:  11125.34 ms
    pure np:  26596.88 ms
    pure np (no copy):  24165.19 ms
=========sqrt==========
    np loop:  5107.81 ms
    pure np:  13542.24 ms
    pure np (no copy):  10445.66 ms
```

With bigger images (`arr_size = (30, 300, 300)`):

```
=========mean==========
    np loop:  24655.34 ms
    pure np:  72427.00 ms
    pure np (no copy):  66605.25 ms
=========sqrt==========
    np loop:  16771.90 ms
    pure np:  38191.14 ms
    pure np (no copy):  30087.40 ms
```

I tested the same with a lots of different functions (`maximum`, `multipy`, `log1p`, and some cv2 functions), all with the same results. I can't wrap my head around this, as the most basic Python programming principle is *use Numpy, as it is much much faster than loops*. Does anyone have any idea why this happens? And more importantly: what can I do to speed up my script if omitting loops doesn't help?

This is the complete script I was using for testing (Numpy version: 1.26.4):

```py
import timeit

arr_size = (30, 100, 100)  # 30 images of size 100x100

init_script = f"import numpy as np;" \
              f"a = np.random.rand(*{arr_size}).astype(np.float32);" \
              f"b = np.random.rand(*{arr_size}).astype(np.float32);" \
              f"out = np.empty_like(a)"

mean_tests = {
    "np loop": "for i, (a_slice, b_slice) in enumerate(zip(a, b)): out[i] = (a_slice+b_slice)/2",
    "pure np": "out[:] = (a+b)/2",
    "pure np (no copy)": "out = (a+b)/2",
}

sqrt_tests = {
    "np loop": "for i, a_slice in enumerate(a): out[i] = np.sqrt(a_slice)",
    "pure np": "out[:] = np.sqrt(a)",
    "pure np (no copy)": "out = np.sqrt(a)",
}

tests = {"mean": mean_tests, "sqrt": sqrt_tests}

for func, test in tests.items():
    print(f"========={func}==========")
    for test_case, cmd in test.items():
        elapsed = timeit.timeit(cmd, init_script, number=10000)
        print(f"\t{test_case}: {elapsed*1000: .2f} ms")
```

Comment: Using numpy instead of python loops isn't a principle, it's a rule of thumb.  But it doesn't always apply.  For small cases, the cost of setting up the arrays is too costly.  And as you found, working with too big arrays is costly.  Instead I suggest a modest number of loops on a complex task.  `numpy` provides building blocks that move iterations to fast compiled code, but using those blocks blindly is not optimal (time wise).

Answer (score 1):

Allocating "big" arrays seems to be the culprit. I can speed up these calculations by using the `out` parameter of the numpy functions, or doing the calculation inplace:

```py
np.add(a, b, out=out)
out /= 2
```

for mean, and

```py
np.sqrt(a, out=out)
```

for sqrt.

I can do something similar for the looped version for some speedup:

```py
for i, (a_slice, b_slice) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    np.add(a_slice, b_slice, out=out[i])
    out[i]/=2
```

and

```py
for i, a_slice in enumerate(a):
    np.sqrt(a_slice, out=out[i])
```

The new results:

```
=========mean==========
    np loop:  3193.34 ms
    pure np:  8400.82 ms
    pure np (no copy):  7102.62 ms
    inplace np:  1165.70 ms
    np inplace loop:  2167.79 ms
=========sqrt==========
    np loop:  1428.44 ms
    pure np:  4185.10 ms
    pure np (no copy):  3459.68 ms
    inplace np:  588.06 ms
    np inplace loop:  860.07 ms
```

For `arr_size=(100,100,100)`:

```
=========mean==========
    np loop:  11747.72 ms
    pure np:  27096.73 ms
    pure np (no copy):  23890.63 ms
    inplace np:  5679.39 ms
    np inplace loop:  8931.12 ms
=========sqrt==========
    np loop:  5062.36 ms
    pure np:  13357.57 ms
    pure np (no copy):  10620.47 ms
    inplace np:  2488.66 ms
    np inplace loop:  3279.80 ms
```

For `arr_size=(30, 300, 300):

```
=========mean==========
    np loop:  24232.15 ms
    pure np:  78151.40 ms
    pure np (no copy):  64296.45 ms
    inplace np:  21251.48 ms
    np inplace loop:  23041.19 ms
=========sqrt==========
    np loop:  14685.71 ms
    pure np:  37801.05 ms
    pure np (no copy):  30844.35 ms
    inplace np:  9997.73 ms
    np inplace loop:  10121.31 ms
```

Comment: I guess using `out=`  and `/=` is the crucial thing. Because what really brings up the calculation time in your "pure np" and "pure np (no copy)" versions is the necessary intermediate memory reservations: If you directly calculate `a + b / 2`, then extra memory needs to be reserved for the intermediate result of `a + b` and probably again for division by 2. This constitutes overhead, both in memory and time. If you calculate instead `np.add(a, b, out=out); out /= 2`, then no extra memory will be required, as only existing arrays, and thus reserved memory, is used for intermediate results.

Comment: Of course intermediate memory reservation is also necessary in the "loop" versions. However, the individual necessary junks of memory are particularly small and also the same size for each iteration, so probably the same small piece of memory gets allocated again and again, thus reducing the overhead.